# installing rsync stops with error in subprocess

Tags: debian, rsync, apt, installation

I tried to install rsync on my vserver which is running on Debian Squeeze.

After calling **apt-get install rsync** the installer stops working with the following output:

```
$ apt-get install rsync
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  rsync
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 359 kB of archives.
After this operation, 721 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://debian.netcup.net/debian/ squeeze/main rsync amd64 3.0.7-2 [359 kB]
Fetched 359 kB in 0s (7480 kB/s)
Selecting previously deselected package rsync.
(Reading database ... 18123 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking rsync (from .../rsync_3.0.7-2_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up rsync (3.0.7-2) ...
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
insserv: warning: script 'halt' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service umountfs and halt if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service halt at depth 5
insserv:  loop involving service umountroot at depth 4
insserv: There is a loop between service umountfs and halt if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service umountfs at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 3
insserv: There is a loop between service halt and umountroot if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service umountnfs at depth 28
insserv: warning: script 'halt' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service umountfs and halt if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service halt at depth 5
insserv:  loop involving service umountroot at depth 4
insserv: There is a loop between service umountfs and halt if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service umountfs at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 3
insserv: There is a loop between service halt and umountroot if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service umountnfs at depth 28
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing rsync (--configure):
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
configured to not write apport reports Errors were encountered while processing:
  rsync
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Before this installation the apt-get install worked fine every time.
I took a backup before I tried to install git-core, so it's no problem for me to reset my system and check whether it worked well before trying to install git.

But I cannot figure out the problem!

Comment: error occurs in rsync, not in git-core! So I tried to install rsync and got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occured because /etc/default/halt was symlinked to /bin/true.

This was possible in earlier releases. But till Debian 6 InitScripts looks for dependencies in the header of the script files. Because halt was symlinked to a value InitScripts could not parse the result and resulted in an error.

Replacing /etc/default/halt by its original content solved the problem.